# Operator Overloading of class object not working while accessing vector element which contains it?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, operator-overloading

I have done the following operator overloading which works as expected on the following class object.
But when I pass this pointer to class object in the vector, the output stream doesn't work
(in the manner I defined it)

I'm sorry for this type of question but I am new in C++ and I don't know how to ask this exactly.

**Operator Overloading:(shape.cpp)**

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, Shape &S)
{
    output << S.name << " (" << S.id << ") " << endl;
    return output;
}
```

**Inside Shape Class(shape.h):** `friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, Shape &S);`

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::cout;
int main()
{
    vector<Shape*> array;
    Shape * s1 = new Shape("Square");

    array.push_back(s1);
    cout << *s1; //Prints "Square (1)" 
    cout << array[0]; //Prints "007CADC8" maybe hex address of vector element?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's `ship` actually? Can't spot it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ little typo. pardon me for that

Comment: _@wing_ Well, more _little typos_. You've been missing to derefernce your pointer stored in `array`, `ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, Shape &S)` should be `ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const Shape &S)`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am not entirely familiar with concept of `constness`
yet, I only know that by adding `const`, the function can control both `const` and non-`const` data, right?
But thanks anyway for your remarks!

Comment: _@wing_ You don't want to change `Shape &S` when just outputting it . You want to work your output operator for rvalues as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This fails because you are outputting a `Shape *`, similar to what would happen if you did `cout << s1`. You need to do the same thing you did in the prior line and dereference the pointer contained in the vector:

```
cout << *array[0];
```

Comment: Nice, thanks so the name of the process was dereference?

cout<< &array[0] would work? presuming it was a vector of Shape&.

Comment: @wing Unary `*` is the indirection operator, which dereferences its operand. And you can't have a vector of references; `std::vector<Shape&>` makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
cout << array[0];
```

is equivalent to:

```
Ship* shipPtr = array[0];
cout << shipPtr;
```

You are just inserting a pointer to `cout`.

Use

```
cout << *array[0];
```

to print the object.

Also, as a programming style, remove the `endl` in the `operator<<` function. Add it only in the calling function.

The `operator<<` function:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, Shape &S)
{
    output << S.name << " (" << S.id << ") "; // Remove endl
    return output;
}
```

Usage:

```
cout << *s1 << endl;
cout << *array[0] << endl;
```

This also allows the calling function to use:

```
Shape* s1 = new Shape("Square");
Shape* s2 = new Shape("Circle");

cout << *s1 << "," << *s2 << endl;
```

Comment: @R Sahu array[0] its a pointer to a pointer,
So I need to write * in front of array to access the pointer of the pointer that shows the object?

That means the hex adress above is that of shipPtr(the pointer of the object) ?

Comment: @wing, Since `array` is a `vector<Ship*>`, `array[0]` is just a `Ship*`, not a pointer to a pointer.